# Showing manually added value as the last option with ngOptions of Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I am creating a select input using ngOption.

```
<select ng-model="foo" ng-options="foo.bar for foo in foos">
  <option value="">Add New</option>
</select>
```

Now It is showing the  option as the first option in my select input but I want to show the  option as the last option in my input. How can I do so?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to `push` a "Add New" option onto `foos`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported by `ngOptions`.  Your options are:

- Push an "Add New" object onto `foos`
- Use `ng-repeat` instead of `ng-options` - (don't do this, it is way more trouble than you would think)
- Write (or find) a `ng-options`-like directive that works the way you want